# Why is this sample code in java not working?

Tags: java, neo4j

In the java section of this page: https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-load-json-from-url/

The line

```
db.execute(query, singletonMap("json",json));
```

gives an error, that is `The method execute(String, Map<String,Map>) is undefined for the type GraphDatabaseService`.

There is no method named "execute" in the class GraphDatabaseService and I can not find the documentation regarding this class. Does anyone know what happeed?

Did the neo4j change its library and did not adjust the code accordingly or did I miss some library to download (I have downloaded neo4j-kernel-1.8.1.jar and neo4j-java-driver-1.1.0.sources.jar and added them to path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Neo4j 2.2.0 or later.**

The `execute` methods have been added to `GraphDatabaseService` with version 2.2.0.

Compare: [Neo4J 2.2.0](https://static.javadoc.io/org.neo4j/neo4j/2.2.0/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html) versus [Neo4J 2.1.8](https://static.javadoc.io/org.neo4j/neo4j/2.1.8/org/neo4j/graphdb/GraphDatabaseService.html)

Also note that `GraphDatabaseService` moved to `neo4j-graphdb-api-x.y.z.jar` in newer revisions whereas you find it in `neo4j-kernel-x.y.z.jar` for older revisions.